# Memory problems while converting cvMat to UIImage

Tags: objective-c, swift, opencv, automatic-ref-counting, bridge

before posting this question here, i have read all the materials and similar posts on it but i cant get the main "idea" what is happening and how to fix it, in 10 of the similar question, everyone was fixing this problem with `@autoreleasepool` in this case i was unable to achive my goal. So while converting cvMat to UIImage i have increasing memory depending on size.

Below are step which i am doing before converting mat to uiimage:

```
cv::Mat undistorted = cv::Mat(cvSize(maxWidth,maxHeight), CV_8UC1);
cv::Mat original = [MatStructure convertUIImageToMat:adjustedImage];

cv::warpPerspective(original, undistorted, cv::getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst), cvSize(maxWidth, maxHeight));
original.release();

adjustedImage = [MatStructure convertMatToUIImage:undistorted];
undistorted.release();
```

problem is visible while i am converting my mat to uiimage, memory goes up to 400 mb and on every cycle it rises.

```
+ (UIImage *) convertMatToUIImage: (cv::Mat) cvMat {
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize() * cvMat.total()];

        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
        if (cvMat.elemSize() == 1) {
            colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
        } else {
            colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        }

        CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef) data);
        CGBitmapInfo bmInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big;

        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(cvMat.cols,                              // width
                                            cvMat.rows,                              // height
                                            8,                                       // bits per component
                                            8 * cvMat.elemSize(),                    // bits per pixel
                                            cvMat.step.p[0],                         // bytesPerRow
                                            colorSpace,                              // colorspace
                                            bmInfo,                                  // bitmap info
                                            provider,                                // CGDataProviderRef
                                            NULL,                                    // decode
                                            false,                                   // should interpolate
                                            kCGRenderingIntentDefault                // intent
                                            );

        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];
        CGImageRelease(imageRef);
        CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        cvMat.release(); // this line is optional.

        return image;
    }
```

I have seen many similar code but every single example works as this one. 
I belive that problem holds in `(__bridge CFDataRef)` and `ARC` cant clean up this data, if i will try to `CFRelease((__bridge CFDataRef)data)` than will happen crash because program will search for allocated memory and it will be freed already so it will run to crash.

I am using `openCV3` and have tried their method `MatToUIImage` but problem still exsits, on `leaks` profiler there are no leaks at all, and most expensive task in memory is `convertMatToUIImage`.

I am reading all day about it but actually can't find any useful solution yet.

Currently i work on `swift 3.0` which inherits `class XXX` and it uses `objC` class to crop something and than return to `UIImage` as well. In `deinit` i am assigning this inherited class property nil, but problem still exsists.Also i think that `dataWithBytes` is duplicating memory like if i have `16MB` at start after creating `NSData` it will be `32MB`..

And please if you can suggests useful threads about this problem i will be glad to read them all. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on this problem more than three days, i had to rewrite function and it worked 100%, i have tested on five different devices.

`CFRelease`, `Free(`) and `@autoreleasepool` did not helped me at all and i implemented this:

```
data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef], 0.2f); // because images are 30MB and up
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFile.jpeg"];

[data writeToFile:appFile atomically:NO];

data = nil;
```

after this solution everything worked fine. So i grab the `UIImage` and converting to `NSData`, after that we should save it to the local directory and the only thing left is to read the data from `directory`. hope this thread will help someone one day.